# File editing using perl

Tags: perl

I have a big file (having more than 20,000 lines) where some of the lines are staring with "+". It is of the form:

```
This is a file with many lines
Some lines start with plus
+ line one
+ line two
Some lines do
not start with plus
+ line three
+ line four
```

I want to join all the lines starting with + with the previous line. So my output  should look like:

```
This is a file with many lines
Some lines start with plus line one line two
Some lines do
not start with plus line three line four
```

How can I do this with perl?

Answer (score 1):

In-place file edit,

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{ $/ ="\n+" } chomp' file
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Perhaps consider: `BEGIN{ $/ .= "+" }`

Comment: @Miller perhaps, but this way seems more clear (to me at least :))